# Speeding Up C# App that opens multiple Excel files

Tags: c#, optimization, excel-interop

I wrote an application with C#. In this App I need to open and close multiple excel files and read/write data to/from them, this cause that the App runs slowly. What method do you suggest to speeding up the App ?

code sample for write data to excel file :

```
        Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Worksheet)(excelBook.Worksheets[1]);
        Range rng;

        rng = excelSheet.get_Range("C2");
        rng.Value2 = txtName.Text;
```

Comment: Maybe a little bit more specific?

Comment: How do you know that is the code that runs slowly? That code doesn't even "write" to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to tell what you are doing without more info.  Assuming that you are doing 'something' with the excel files when you open them you might try turning off screen updating at the beginning of the code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This can have a profound impact on speed if your moving lots of data between sheets or similar actions.

If your leaving it open for the user to do work turn back on the screen updating at the end of your code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 2):

you do not have to open excel file to read/write excel file. you can use OLEDB to do it, it should be much faster. search "OLEDB Excel c#".

here is an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB